# Which partition in my computer has Ubuntu installed on it?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, mount, boot-partition

I was trying to uninstall Ubuntu and install another Linux distro, but I can't figure out which partition in my computer has Linux installed on it.

Results of `fdisk -l` :

```
Device     Boot      Start        End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1          1126400  204802047 203675648  97.1G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2        204802048 1054722047 849920000 405.3G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       1054722048 1707761663 653039616 311.4G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4       1707763710 1953523711 245760002 117.2G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5  *    1707763712 1708249087    485376   237M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
/dev/sda6       1708251136 1953523711 245272576   117G 83 Linux
```

Results of `parted -l` :

```
Number  Start  End     Size   Type      File system  Flags
 1      577MB  105GB   104GB  primary   ntfs
 2      105GB  540GB   435GB  primary   ntfs
 3      540GB  874GB   334GB  primary   ntfs
 4      874GB  1000GB  126GB  extended
 5      874GB  875GB   249MB  logical   fat32        boot, esp
 6      875GB  1000GB  126GB  logical   ext4
```

Results of `df` :

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev             1876516         0   1876516   0% /dev
tmpfs             380164      2100    378064   1% /run
/dev/sda6      120186624  28642772  85395656  26% /
tmpfs            1900820     85228   1815592   5% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120         4      5116   1% /run/lock
tmpfs            1900820         0   1900820   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop1        419328    419328         0 100% /snap/gimp/227
/dev/loop4           256       256         0 100% /snap/gtk2-common-themes/5
/dev/loop5         15104     15104         0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/375
/dev/loop8         13312     13312         0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/139
/dev/loop17        93184     93184         0 100% /snap/core/6350
/dev/loop10        56064     56064         0 100% /snap/core18/1650
/dev/loop2          1024      1024         0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/81
/dev/loop0         91264     91264         0 100% /snap/core/8268
/dev/loop6          4352      4352         0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/544
/dev/loop9        185472    185472         0 100% /snap/spotify/36
/dev/loop15        14976     14976         0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/45
/dev/loop24        45312     45312         0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1353
/dev/loop22       160512    160512         0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/110
/dev/loop7         46080     46080         0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1440
/dev/loop12       151808    151808         0 100% /snap/chromium/971
/dev/loop20       144128    144128         0 100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/98
/dev/loop18       144128    144128         0 100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/74
/dev/loop13        55936     55936         0 100% /snap/core18/1288
/dev/loop25        97408     97408         0 100% /snap/telegram-desktop/994
/dev/loop14       151808    151808         0 100% /snap/chromium/986
/dev/loop3        207872    207872         0 100% /snap/vlc/1397
/dev/loop23       189312    189312         0 100% /snap/eclipse/40
/dev/loop19       160384    160384         0 100% /snap/blender/34
/dev/loop21         3840      3840         0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/123
/dev/loop11         3840      3840         0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/57
/dev/loop16         2304      2304         0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/260
/dev/sda2      424959996 299550292 125409704  71% /mnt/2ADAC21CDAC1E463
tmpfs             380164        16    380148   1% /run/user/121
tmpfs             380164        44    380120   1% /run/user/1000
```

Comment: the output you got is from the OS that you want to uninstall?

Comment: if you want to know it from the Current OS.. you can run `lsblk` and check for `/` Partition.. https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVZtv.png

Comment: @YuganTej yeah.

Comment: So, did you run the command `lsblk` ?

Comment: @YuganTej It showed this result, https://i.imgur.com/vQ686Vu.png

Comment: yes its `sda6` partition

Comment: @guiverc I was trying to install kubuntu, I was trying to free up the space ubuntu is taking as it will probably be easier and because the guys on youtube was doing so.

Comment: all NTFS partitions are windows (NTFS = a modified HPFS or IBM's OS/2 fs; microsoft called it NTFS as it was used by NT), EFI is used by your system with boot details for UEFI, leaving the ext4 (sda6) used by a GNU/Linux distro you've indicated was Ubuntu.  Kubuntu should detect it as Ubuntu, and offer to replace Ubuntu with itself (this may vary on release which you didn't specify), but I'd expect it to be super easy & not require anything difficult.  Backup regardless (better safe than sorry)  https://userbase.kde.org/Kubuntu/Installation

Comment: @guiverc Thanks mate. FYI, I was trying to install kubuntu 18.04.03 but it didn't gave any option to install kubuntu inplace of ubuntu.

Comment: @guiverc The only options which it gave me were this https://i.imgur.com/ZbkDFrx.jpg. Can I still install kubuntu without deleting ubuntu?

Comment: Yep, I'm pretty sure. You can even google kubuntu installer and see the images which exactly matches with my image.

Comment: Sorry I grabbed a 18.04.4 iso & booted; it's a `ubiquity kde_ui` frontend that looks like `calamares`.. I would in your case backup your data, use the "Manual" partitioning and install over your existing sda6/Ubuntu partition (ie. change that partition, mark is as your "/" mount point, etc).

Comment: Thanks. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

From what you have posted your

> / aka root

partition is mounted on

> /dev/sda6

which is where your installation exists.

Alternatively you can also use [findmnt](https://linux.die.net/man/8/findmnt) which will give you the mount point of various partitions.

If you are on windows generally the big unknown partition block in disk management is where "Ubuntu" or any other linux distro gets shown up as.

Be very careful while deleting it as it could possibly delete your home directory as well, which is where most of your files will be.